# Unable to add more panel and section in WordPress customizer. I need 2 panel and 3 section. but cant understand why my cods are not working

Tags: php, wordpress

**using these code in functions.php, its working but when I want add more panel or section its not working.** 
I have seen too many suggestions and related post but disappointed.  Most of the tutorial are related to color option in customizer.

I could not identify what actually the problem is.

```
function my_customize_register( $wp_customize ){
$wp_customize->add_panel('zakaraia_panel',array(
        'title' => 'Custom Theme Option',
        'priority' => '10',
        'description' => ' this is a customize theme options panel'
));



$wp_customize->add_section( 'counter_section', array(
    'title' => __( 'Counter', 'flexor' ),
    'priority' => 5,
    'description' => __( 'Description of section', 'flexor' ),
    'panel' => 'zakaraia_panel',
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'counter_default_number', array(
    'default' => 'Counter Default number',
    'transport' => 'refresh'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'counter_default_number', array(
    'section'   => 'counter_section',
    'label' => 'input counter number here',
    'description' => 'this is a description of counter number here',
    'type'   => 'text' 


) );



$wp_customize->add_setting( 'counter_default_text', array(
    'default' => 'Counter Default Text',
    'transport' => 'refresh'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'counter_default_text', array(
    'section'   => 'counter_section',
    'label' => 'input counter text here',
    'description' => 'this is a text description input counter text here',
    'type'   => 'text' 


) );




    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'counter_default_link', array(
    'default' => 'Counter Default Text',
    'transport' => 'refresh'
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'counter_default_link', array(
    'section'   => 'counter_section',
    'label' => 'input counter link paste here',
    'description' => 'this is a link description',
    'type'   => 'text' 


) );
```

}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_customize_register' );

Comment: how you are calling my_customize_register ?

Comment: add_action( 'customize_register', 'my_customize_register' );

Comment: there is some duplication in your code, you are adding the same setting and control more than once